# How to convert String to Date value in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to convert a String to Date in SAS, I tried:

```
data _null_; 
   monyy = '05May2013'; 
   date = input(substr(strip(monyy),1,9),yymmdd.);;
   put date=date9.; 
   run;
```

But it did not work.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need substr or strip.

```
input(monyy,date9.);
```

Answer (score 15):

Formats like

```
date9.
```

or

```
mmddyy10.
```

are not valid for input command while converting text to a sas date. You can use

```
Date = input( cdate , ANYDTDTE11.);
```

or

```
Date = input( cdate , ANYDTDTE10.);
```

for conversion.

Comment: I had an input character variable that looked like '1961-11-20' that I wanted to read as a date.  This solution worked, where the others did not.

Comment: Agreed, this solution works better for character datetime stamps as well.

Answer (score 3):

As stated above, the simple answer is:

```
date = input(monyy,date9.);
```

with the addition of:

```
put date=yymmdd.;
```

The reason *why* this works, and what you did doesn't, is because of a common misunderstanding in SAS.  DATE9. is an INFORMAT.  In an INPUT statement, it provides the SAS interpreter with a set of translation commands it can send to the compiler to turn your text into the right numbers, which will then look like a date once the right FORMAT is applied.  FORMATs are just visible representations of numbers (or characters).  So by using YYMMDD., you confused the INPUT function by handing it a FORMAT instead of an INFORMAT, and probably got a helpful error that said:

```
Invalid argument to INPUT function at line... etc...
```

Which told you absolutely nothing about what to do next.

In summary, to represent your character date as a YYMMDD. In SAS you need to:

1. change the INFORMAT - `date = input(monyy,date9.);`
2. apply the FORMAT - `put date=YYMMDD10.;`

Comment: If you can't comment don't use a answer to do it. Get enough reputation and then comment.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau On the other hand, this is probably one occasion where it honestly is more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
data _null_; 
   monyy = '05May2013'; 
   date = input(substr(strip(monyy),1,9),date9.);
   put date=date9.; 
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

input(char_val, date9.);

You can consider to convert it to word format using
input(char_val, worddate.)

You can get a lot in this page http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm

Answer (score 1):

This code helps:

```
data final; set final;

first_date = INPUT(compress(char_date),date9.); format first_date date9.;

run;
```

I personally have tried it on SAS

Answer (score 0):

```
input(char_val,current_date_format);
```

You can specify any date format at display time, like set `char_val=date9.;`