# character to date in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a field that has dates in it in character format that display as 31-DEC-2020 or similar, and I need to convert them to mmddyy10.

How would I go about doing that? I have tried to use INPUT() so far, to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `date_var = input(str_var, date11.)`.

```
/* test data */
data have;
     input s $ 1-11;
     cards;
31-DEC-2020
01-jan-1970
;run;

/* code */
data want;
    set have;
    date = input(s, date11.);
    format date date11.;  /* display format need not be date11. */
run;
```

Result

```
    s            date
1   31-DEC-2020  31-DEC-2020    
2   01-jan-1970  01-JAN-1970
```

The data type of the output dataset can be verified using `proc contents data=want; run;` (omitted here).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647134) and the [official docs](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000194757.htm).